# Undefined property in model class

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Please any reason why this code is throwing this error Undefined property: App\Models\EventScheduler::$eventable_type

```php
protected function attendeesProfile(): Attribute
{
    $isCohortEvent = $this->eventable_type === CohortActivity::$polyMorphType;

    $profiles = collect([]);

    return Attribute::make(

        get: fn () =>  $profiles,
    );
}
```

eventable_type is a property loaded from the database

I also try to log the property and I get the value logged correctly, but that line still throws the error, the property is also successful accessible in another attribute method

Comment: Please post the full model